# Whats the difference in these two ways of passing url parameters "/blog/12" vs "/blog?id=12"

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, url

i'm struggling to understand what's the difference between there two ways(`/blog/12` vs `/blog?id=12`) of passing parameters to the url.

In which cases one is superior over the other? Are there any general recommendations about which one to use?

Comment: Historically SEO prefers /blog/12 and that format is also usually easier for users to recall and/or modify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `/blog?id=12` you request access to the `/blog` page (whichever it is - depends on routing) and pass `id=12` parameter to id.

In `/blog/12` the router determines what page is accessed. Most commonly it's configured to access the `/blog` page again, and automatically pass `id=12` parameter to it.

The latter approach requires more configuration but ends with more user- and SEO-friendly URLs.

Comment: To give your users and search engines an even better experience, consider using slugs instead of IDs in your URLs using the router method. Something like [`slug` on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/slug) can help you build these automatically.

Comment: That's correct, you mean that `/blog/introduction-to-routing` is better than `/blog/12` for both users and search engines.